# Shared Library websphere

Tags: websphere, shared

I want to create share library in Websphere Application Server. I have abc.jar inside abc folder. I want to know the difference between specifying c:\abc Vs c:\abc\abc.jar in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

If c:\abc contains other jars, they will also be added to the classpath.  If c:\abc contains non-jar files (e.g., c:\abc\test.properties), then c:\abc will be added to the classpath itself, which allows getResource calls for the directory to work (e.g., ClassLoader.getResource("test.properties") will find the file).